# which is a better way to show text over a button in android layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, textview

Is there any reason I should prefer this xml

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/inputBox"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/input_box_idle"
                android:padding="0dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/verificationCodeEditText"
                style="@style/textOnBg"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:text="- - - -"
                android:textColor="#00bcfe"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:textStyle="italic" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

over this one?

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/inputBox"
    style="@style/textOnBg"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/input_box_idle"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:text="- - - -"
    android:textColor="#00bcfe"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:textStyle="italic" />
```

will it be easier to change and manipulate text with the first xml?

Comment: of course you should opt to 2nd choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be the same for both, since `Button` extends `TextView`: [api](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html)

---

**CORRECTION**

I had a bit of a brain fart there. I saw it extends `TextView`, not `EditText`. Sorry for that...

Comment: so why I cannot use EditText method `public void setSelection (int index)` on Button ?

Comment: `((EditText))mInputBox).setSelection(s.length());` why i get this error: `Cannot cast from Button to EditText`

Answer (score 0):

It is always better to reduce the Views rendered on the Activity which improves the UI rendering of the application.

Hope you have referred to this link.
http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html

Therefore, i would recommend using approach 2.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion if they both get the job done to the specifications you want without affecting performance then you should go with the more condensed version as it will be easier look at.

It's a matter of opinion on how you want it to look, Yes user opinion matters but really what it comes down to in this case is how you want it to look and feel.

Run a controlled test with each one and attempt the actions you want to accomplish with them. then compare which one you like better.

Personally I would choose the 2nd one because it's a bit easier on the eyes to see a small chunk than a big one, assuming it did the job i wanted of it.